# Saving and loading multidimensional arrays using Json in Android

Tags: android, json, multidimensional-array, large-files

I am writing an android app that has several large multi-dimensional arrays of data like float[][][][], which should be loaded at the beginning of application run. So I need to read and load them from files, stored in phone storage.
The problem I have with typical solution of reading from files, is that it takes so long to read and load all of them and I am looking for a faster option.
I decided to give a try to Json for mentioned purpose, but I couldn't find any way to store multi-dimensional arrays like float[][][][]. Can anybody propose any clues to help me? Also if you know a better solution rather than Json for my situation, I would really appreciate to hear.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A multidimensional array is simply an array of arrays of arrays (repeat for additional dimensions).

Creating a 2d array of floats would go something like this:

```
float[][] array; // your array
JSONArray outerJsonArray = new JsonArray();

for (int i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
  JSONArray innerJsonArray = new JsonArray(); 

  for (int j=0; j < array[i].length; j++) innerJsonArray.put(array[i][j]);

  outerJsonArray.put(innerJsonArray);
}
```

To convert higher dimensional arrays to json, you simply increase the nesting of the loop to match the dimensionality of the array.

Comment: Thank you very much, what about reading them and loading into arrays? As it seems, I need to load each arrays values, one by one and through 4 consecutive nested loops, is that correct?  Is there another faster way?